# Get thread id and terminate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, win-universal-app, uwp

I have an async method that can run multiple times in the same time. This method perform a call to a server so it takes some time to complete. I want each time an instance of this method is called to stop the execution of the same method that run in the same time. I was thinking about creating a list of thread id and everytime the method is called the threads that created for the execution of the older instances of this method will be terminated.

So what i am looking for is a way to get the current thread id that a specific method is running from, and the way to terminate a thread using its id.

PS. I've checked all posts about finding thread id etc but none of these work in UWP.

Comment: UWP have absolutely no idea about threads, so that's not what you want. Please start by posting an [MCVE] so we can help you determine the best approach.

Comment: When you start a thread you can get the ID from the variable used to start it. The [`Thread.ManagedThreadID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid(v=vs.110).aspx) property gives you an ID to use.

Comment: This code is not working in UWP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *UWP* you don't have ability to control threads. But you can surely control tasks, and for example, cancel it if needed with with [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx):

```cs
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    // your job here
}, tokenSource.Token);

// then if you want to cancel the job use tokenSource:
tokenSource.Cancel();
```

Note that this is only a simple example of using *CancellationToken* with *Task.Run*, but most of async methods uses these tokens and even you can convert them to task which will use one.

More about task cancellation you will find [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx), [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-4.html) and more.

Comment: I have an async void method can i generate and use the CancellationTokenSource there too without using Task.Run ?

Comment: @ChrisK Yes you can use token in method - remember that critical is line *token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested* - at that line if your program sees that there is a cancel request it will throw cancel exception. So this is up to you at what moment task/method will be cancelled. Note also that Runtime operations can be extended with [AsTask()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779747(v=vs.110).aspx) which supports cancellation.

Comment: So i cant just cancel the execution of a Task and its childred by just calling token.Cancel, i have to check if cancelation requested an then for example  just ignore the results returned from the method?

Comment: @ChrisK Everything depends on your implementation. Note also that when you cancel something you should handle that case also in cancelled method. The best would be if you have just try it yourself - debug and you will find all the answers.